# Function to generate arrays with given choices Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to output something like: [array([-1,  1, -1]), array([-1,  1,  1])] etc. 100 times. I have been editing my code without success for invalid syntax.

```
test = []
i =1
def testdata():
    while i<= 100:
        new = [random.choices([-1,1], k=3) for _ in range(100)]
        test.append(new) 
        np.array(n) for n in new.values()[:3]
        i += 1
        return new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random as r
c = [-1, 1]
[np.array([r.choice(c), r.choice(c), r.choice(c)]) for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: one possible alternative: `new = [np.random.choice([-1,1], 3) for i in range(100)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
return np.array(random.choices([-1, 1], k=3*100)).reshape(100, 3)
```